# Form text color

Tags: html, forms

In a form, in the imput "text" how to have a color for the text value, before the user enters anything and another color for the text that the user enters?

(I don't mean input:focus, this is just when the user writes. I'm looking for a different color when he leaves the field also)

I have the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/JQSZE/

```
<form>
    <input type="text" value="nom" />
</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you try something like `input { color: grey; } input:focus { color: black; }`. That way whenever the user focuses on the input, all the text will be rendered grey, including the additional characters he types, and they will turn black once he focuses off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaScript focus and blur event.

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("input").focus(function(){
         jQuery(this).css("color", "red");
    }).blur(function(){
         jQuery(this).css("color", "green");
    });
});​
```

Comment: Very good answer, clear and simple and it doesn't need any css change. I applied here if someone want to see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/JQSZE/7/

Answer (score 2):

use jQuery to alter the class of the element once it leaves focus. You could easily add a few levels of complexity by checking if they've entered content before applying the class etc.

Here you go, here's a basic example:

http://jsfiddle.net/erinfreeman/q348G/

Comment: This is clear and works fine in Fiddle. But something strange happens, when I copy paste to my document, it doesn't work. So I try in jsbin because we can share all the code in one place. It doesn't work here either. What is missing?: http://jsbin.com/isobek/1/edit What is missing?

Comment: If someone looks to this example be careful. When I tried to copy paste the example from the fiddle: jsbin.com/isobek/1/edit to an editor It generates a hidden character that ruins it all. Dreamweaver and a lot of editors don't detect it. At the end I could find that JS Bin marcs that hidden character with a red point that I could delete. Here is the solution without the hidden character that can be copy paste without problems: http://jsbin.com/isobek/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

you can also try like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").focus(function(){       
        (this).css("color", "green");
});
```

});​

or smply try

```
$('input').css("color","green");
```

That's it